# Where is the ambiguity in my grammar?

Tags: python, compiler-construction, grammar, ply, shift-reduce-conflict

I have the following ambiguous grammar where the capital letter rules are for simple lexical tokens:

```
program : function | function program
function : FN ID ARROW TYPE invariants DASH block
fn_call : ID L_PAREN CONSTANT R_PAREN


invariants : invariant | invariant invariants
invariant : TYPE ID COLON invariant_tests
invariant_tests : test | test COMMA invariant_tests
test : OPERATOR CONSTANT | STAR


block : expression | expression block
expression : loop | fn_call | assignment | def | constant
loop : FOR def IN CONSTANT COLON block
assignment : ID ASSIGN CONSTANT | ID ASSIGN ID
def : TYPE assignment
```

I receive 8 shift/reduce errors (when using Python 2.7 and PLY).

Is the ambiguity a result of how I define "one or more", eg. `block : expression | expression block`?

Comment: Just out of curiosity; why do you use PLY (built upon the older Lex and Yacc) instead of Flex and Bison?

Comment: @nic I'm more comfortable in Python, as opposed to C. Since this is my first grammar I thought I should stay in home waters. Are there enormous benefits to using Flex/Bison?

Comment: Flex is said to be significantly faster than Lex (even though lexing is a fast task as it is it might be good to know) and released under a Berkeley license (Lex is released under some AT&T license).. Bison I believe is a lot more stable than Yacc. It's weird that PLY is built on the old versions.. I think for just playing around L&Y is as good as F&B and if you need to it's easy to make the switch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a previous speaker said, you must differentiate between the "block usages". 
For example, try:

```
loop : FOR def IN CONSTANT COLON block END FOR
```

Comment: The previous speaker was me - but since I can't accept my answer for a few days, I will accept your correct answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was how I defined the `loop`:

`loop : FOR def IN CONSTANT COLON block`

since the parser didn't understand if the block belonged to the loop or to the function.

Basically, another variant of the dangling else problem.